# Java: cannot repaint()?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint, paintcomponent

I am writing some code to create coloured visualisations of text. The following managed the visualisation panel and the setCT(String c) method is (correctly) called from elsewhere in the program.

Unfortunately, the required visualisation only happens when the window is resized. Until then, the vis panel just stays black! What is going on? I've tried using the validate() method and also creating a new Runnable() as per the guides elsewhere, to no avail. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Visualiser extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3936526023655045114L;
    public static final Color DEFAULT_BG_COL = Color.black;
    private static Color bgCol;
    private static String ct;
    private static BufferedImage stat;
    private static boolean doVis=false;
    private Timer refreshTimer=new Timer(100, this);

    public Visualiser() {
        this(200, 250);
    }

    public Visualiser(int w, int h) {

        super.setSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        bgCol = Visualiser.DEFAULT_BG_COL;      
        super.setBackground(bgCol);
        stat = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        refreshTimer.start();


    }


    /*public void paint(Graphics g) {
     * REPLACED BY paintComponent() METHOD AS PER SUGGESTION
        super.paint(g);
        if (Visualiser.doVis==true) {
            System.out.println("passed doVis test");
            doVis(g);
        }

    }*/

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(Visualiser.doVis) {
            doVis(g);
        }
    }

    public Color getBGCol() {
        return bgCol;
    }

    public void setBGCol(Color b) {
        bgCol = b;
        super.setBackground(bgCol);
    }

    public void doVis(Graphics g) {
        // all of my code to actually paint the visualisation is here
        //doStatic(g);
        // establish the block size and height using length of the string
        int numBlocks = 3*ct.length();
        if (numBlocks != 0) {
            int blockSize = (int) Math.sqrt((this.getWidth()*this.getHeight())/numBlocks) ;
            Graphics2D g2 = stat.createGraphics();
            int blocksX=Math.round(this.getWidth()/blockSize);
            int blocksY=Math.round(this.getHeight()/blockSize);
            char chars[]=ct.toCharArray();
            int c=0;
            int cc=0;
            for(int i = 1; i< blocksX; i++) {
                for(int j=1; j<blocksY; j++) {
                    cc=c+4;
                    if(cc < chars.length) {
                        //System.out.println("char length is: " + chars.length + " and c is: " + c);
                        g2.setColor(new Color((int) chars[c]%255, (int) chars[c+1]%255, (int)chars[c+2]%255));
                        //System.out.println("color: " + g2.getColor().toString());
                    }
                    g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(i*blockSize, j*blockSize, blockSize, blockSize));
                    c++;
                }
            }

            g.drawImage(stat, 0, 0, this);
        }




    }

    private void doStatic(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = stat.createGraphics();
        int x=this.getWidth();
        int y=this.getHeight();
        //System.out.println("x, y: " + x + " " + y);
        for (int i=1; i<x; i++) {
            for(int j=1; j<y; j++) {
                g2.setColor(new Color(getRandom(0, 255), getRandom(0,255), getRandom(0,255)));
                g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(i, j, 1, 1));
            }
        }
        g.drawImage(stat,  0, 0, this);

    }


    private int getRandom(int min, int max) {
        int random = min + (int) (Math.random() * (max - min));

        return random;

    }


    public void setCT(String c) {
        Visualiser.doVis=true;
        ct=c;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("got to the new runnable thingie");

                repaint();
            }
        });


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(this.refreshTimer)) {
            // the timer is the source so do some refreshing!

            repaint();
        }

    }




}
```

The doVis and ct variables are both public static boolean & String respectively of this (the Visualiser) class and the paint method checks the doVis value before deciding what to paint. This part is OK. It is forcing Java to do a proper repaint that is the problem!

Comment: you have extended from a `JPanel`, and the `setCT`-Method is in this extended class?

Comment: sounds like you there is something wrong in the code you are _not_ showing ;-) Time for an SSCCE that demonstrates the problem ...

Answer (score 2):

As you are extending a `JPanel`, the quick, easy and clean way to achieve what you want is to override the `JPanel.paintComponent()` method where you do your rendering.

If you want to automatically refresh your GUI then I suggest you go for swing timers in which you call `JPanel.validate()` every now and then. Your panel can look like:

```
public class TextRendererPanel extends JPanel{
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       // Do your rendering stuff here.
   }
}
```

Once created, the panel can be refreshed like this:

```
TextRendererPanel textRendererPanel = new TextRendererPanel();
textRendererPanel.invalidate();
```

And here is a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) on swing timers that you can start with.

Comment: Our pleasure :) Please see my updates on how to override `paintComponent` method

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I have edited my original  Q to show the full code for the Visualiser class. Key thing was creating a timer object with periodic refresh AND in the class that calls this visualisation, I include a Visualiser.invalidate(); call directly after the Visualiser.setCT() call. This seemed to do the trick!

Comment: Excellent! Glad it worked. Please don't forget to mark this as an answer if you think it resolved your problem ;)

Comment: @GETah : Just a small suggestion, to keep the encapsulation intact, when you overriding `paintComponent()` as far as possible keep the `Access Specifier` the same one, as used in the `Parent Class/Base Class`, which is protected, hence it's `protected void paintComponent(...)` +1 though for the rest :-)

Comment: @GETah : You are MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: @user1509862 and GETah: the paintComponent implementation is invalid in both :-) JPanel's opacity defaults to true, that is it takes the responsibility of filling its background completely, always. So either change to return false or call super.paintComponent or any other means to fill the back